# Unit testing mongoose method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose

I'm new to unit testing, can't wrap my head what I should unit test given this function ? Note that I don't want to hit database, so I need to mock/stub  mongoose built in function "findById" maybe ? Can't figure it out big picture here :).
Not asking for complete solution, just an idea or some pointer to go from there.

```
LyricSchema.statics.like = function(id) {
  const Lyric = mongoose.model('lyric');

  return Lyric.findById(id)
    .then(lyric => {
      ++lyric.likes;
      return lyric.save();
    })
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: You have to stub the findById method to return as a promise an object with with a stubbed function save and finally to expect that this method was called

Comment: A very good tutorial/example is this https://www.sitepoint.com/sinon-tutorial-javascript-testing-mocks-spies-stubs/

Comment: So we just using unit test to check that method was called ? Nothing more ?

Answer (score 1):

**Mockgoose**

https://github.com/mockgoose/mockgoose

But this creates a in memory Database. And the database will serve the actual calls.

Comment: Is memory database faster than actual database ? Won't it take long, to run for example 150 tests ?

Comment: Depends what we define as long.

No, i had around 125 test cases running in around 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple tdd test. I'm use Mocha + chai:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Lyric= mongoose.models.Lyric;

describe("Lyric test", () => {
   let lyricId;

   //create lyric document
   beforeEach(done => {
      Lyric.create({...})
      .then(result=>{
         lyricId = result._id;
         done();
      })
   });

   //remove lyric document after test
   afterEach(done=>{
      Lyric.remove({_id: lyricId})
      .then(()=>{
          done();
      })
   });

   //test like function
   it('like test', done=>{
       Lyric.like(lyricId)
       .then(result=>{
           expect(result.likes).equal(1);
           done();
       })
       .catch(err=>{throw err;})
   });
})
```

Comment: In general it is not a good practise to use real data and services in unit tests. The best way is to stub the functions and the objects.

Comment: Yes this is sort of integration test, if we have 100 test cases for example, tests will take a ton of time to show me if they pass.